# How to send AutoCAD Commands through VBA?

Tags: ms-access, autocad

I'm trying to do the following but through VBA:

1. Open Object
2. Send CTRL+0 (_CleanScreenON)
3. Send MouseClick * 2 = (._ZOOM All)
4. Save and close document returning to Access.

But really, all I need to understand is how to open a drawing and send commands to it. I haven't been successfull.

I'm aware of the [AutoCAD Document Object Documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-9216BFCD-D358-4FC6-B631-B52E6693D242-htm.html) and I've experimented with *SendCommand* and *PostCommand* but I'm getting **Object doesn't support Automation** errors... Can someone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance, Rafael.

EDIT:
This is the code I was experimenting with:

```
Private Sub CenterDWG_Click()
'Me.DrawingFrame.Object.Open
Me.DrawingFrame.Object.SendCommand ("_CleanScreenON")
Me.DrawingFrame.Object.SendCommand ("._ZOOM All")
'Me.DrawingFrame.Object.Regen acAllViewports
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if you control autocad by a external program you has first to set up the autocad object
then you get access to its propertys

```
Public Sub startCommandInAcad()
Dim tAcadApp As AcadApplication
Set tAcadApp = getAcadApp
If (tAcadApp Is Nothing) Then
  Call MsgBox("No AcadApplication found")
Else
  If (tAcadApp.ActiveDocument Is Nothing) Then
     Call MsgBox("No current Drawing found in AutoCAD-Application")
  Else
     On Error Resume Next
     tAcadApp.ActiveDocument.SendCommand ("_-LANDXMLOUT" & vbCr & 
    "C:\TEMP\ExpFile.XML" & vbCr)
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Call MsgBox("Error occured during 'SendCommand'" & vbNewLine & 
    Err.Description)
     End If

     On Error Goto 0
  End If
  End If
End Sub
```

[grabbed example from autodesk forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/visual-basic-customization/excel-vba-send-autocad-commands/td-p/4815049)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have an application that I have developed for this. Below, I have taken some of the code and added it for reference. I tried to clean it up as best as possible, but I am sure there are missing functions in here. If you have any additional questions, don't hesitate to ask.

The application that this code comes from is an access database that we developed here. It holds records for each of our evergreen AutoCAD drawings. It has sub tables to store revision entries with supporting documentation (PDF redlines), block reference information, block attribute reference information, custom drawing properties, and layer information. It does much more than this, but that's another topic.

I have also used late binding instead of a direct reference to AutoCAD as we have users on different versions. This is more difficult to code, but accomplishes the same goal.

Lastly, I am a self-taught programmer and I know that my code is not perfect, but it serves as a great solution for what we needed. Any suggestions are appreciated and welcomed. I hope this helps whoever finds this topic.

## Button Click to Open Drawing

```
Private Sub TxtSketchURL_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

SketchPath = "C:\Test.dwg" '<---Provide your autocad path here

Call getCadDwg(SketchPath)

'-------------------------------------------------------
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure TxtSketchURL_Click of VBA Document Form_Sketch", vbOKOnly
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

## Sub to Open the drawing

```
Public Sub getCadDwg(Dwgpath As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim strMsg As String
Dim booYouHaveItOpen As Boolean
Set CADApp = GetCad
Dim booFileOpen As Boolean
booFileOpen = isFileOpen(Dwgpath)
Dim booFileExists As Boolean

Dim objfso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
booFileExists = objfso.fileExists(Dwgpath)

'See if the file exists and then exit if it doesn't
If booFileExists = False Then
    MsgBox "A file at the below path does not exist." & vbCr & vbCr & vbCr & Dwgpath, vbOKOnly, "File Missing"
End If

If booFileOpen = True Then
    'Search to see if it is the current user that has it opened
    If CADApp.Documents.Count > 0 Then
        For Each myDwg In CADApp.Documents
            'Test to see if one of the current drawing has the same path, then bring it to the front.
            If Dwgpath = myDwg.FullName Or GetUNC(Dwgpath) = myDwg.FullName Then
            booYouHaveItOpen = True
                If myDwg.active = False Then
                    myDwg.Activate
                    Call bringCADToFront
                    Exit For

                End If
            End If
        Next myDwg
    End If

    If booYouHaveItOpen = False Then
                MsgBox "Drawing file is already opened by another user." _
                    , vbInformation + vbOKOnly _
                    , "Drawing Opened Already!"
    End If

    GoTo ExitHere

    Else
        'Open the AutoCAD drawing
        Set myDwg = CADApp.Documents.Open(Dwgpath)


        CADApp.ZoomExtents
        CADApp.Visible = True

End If


'-------------------------------------------------------
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next

    Call bringCADToFront
    Set CADApp = Nothing
    Set myDwg = Nothing

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure getCadDwg of Module mCadLateBind", vbOKOnly

    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

## GetCAD Function

```
Public Function GetCad() As Object

On Error Resume Next

'Check to see if AutoCAD is open
'Set GetCad = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application.19")
Set GetCad = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

'If AutoCAD is NOT open and error number will be produced
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear

    'Open an instance of AutoCAD
    'Set GetCad = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application.19")
    Set GetCad = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")

End If

'Make AutoCAD visible
GetCad.Visible = True


End Function
```

## GetUNCPath Function

```
Public Function GetUNC(strMappedDrive As String) As String
    Dim objfso As FileSystemObject
    Dim objDrive As Drive
    Dim strDrive As String
    Dim strShare As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set objfso = New FileSystemObject


'Get the Drive Name
    strDrive = objfso.GetDriveName(strMappedDrive)
    Set objDrive = objfso.GetDrive(strDrive)
    'find the UNC share name from the mapped letter
    strShare = objDrive.ShareName
    'Replace the MappedDrive With the UNC share name
    GetUNC = Replace(strMappedDrive, strDrive, strShare)

'-------------------------------------------------------
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objfso = Nothing 'Destroy the object
    Set objDrive = Nothing  'Destroy the object
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure GetUNC of Module mFunctions", vbOKOnly

    GoTo ExitHere
End Function
```

## BringCADtoFront

```
Public Sub bringCADToFront()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim CADApp As Variant
Dim lngHwnd As Long
Dim lngMDIHwnd As Long

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Set CADApp = GetCad

lngHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, CADApp.Caption)

SetFocusAPI lngHwnd

'-------------------------------------------------------
ExitHere:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set CADApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure bringCADToFront of Sub mAutoCADsubs", vbOKOnly
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

## Save the AutoCAD drawing

```
myDwg.Close True 'True to save the drawing, False for no save
```